# How do I enable the shell to type a command in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

How exactly do I type commands into emacs, at the bottom? I tried clicking there and it won't work. I tried just typing and it doesn't let me type. I'm trying to run `M-x package-install`

[image]

Comment: `M-x` means **meta-x**, that's probably either your `alt` or `command` key held down and then press `x` ...

Comment: @donkopotamus Thanks for clarifying that meant meta-x. I was able to Google `meta-x emacs` and discovered it's the `ESC` key followed by the `x` key.

Comment: Type `C-h t` (which means `Ctrl`+`h` then `t`) to run the Emacs tutorial, and work your way through it. It will answer all of the need-to-know aspects of starting to use Emacs.